# Ran systemctl --user enable as root and now X server no longer starts

Tags: systemd, x11

I was trying to enable xscreensaver for login and created a service for it. I used a basic service template as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Screensaver

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xscreensaver -no-splash

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I used `sudo systemctl --user enable screensaver.service` and restarted my pc. However upon reboot lighted no longer attempted to try and login and switching over to a tty and manually running `startx` gave no error. It wasn't until I tried running it as sudo that I got this error:

> Failed to connect to bus: No medium found
> dbus-update-activation-enviroment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Using X11 for bus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead
> xinit: connection to X server lost

After this I attempted to undo my changes but found that when I tried to disable the service I would get a service not found error. Searching for the service with `systemctl | grep screensaver.service` returned no results.

After this I deleted the service and the directory I had made in .config/systemd thinking that would fix it but that did not. The environmental variable: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS equals `unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus`. At this point I am out of ideas and was wondering if anyone knew how to undo the damage I did when running `systemctl --user` as root?